# Proving Predicate Logic using Coq - Beginner Syntax

Tags: predicate, coq

I'm trying to prove the following in Coq:

Goal (forall x:X, P(x) /\ Q(x)) -> ((forall x:X, P (x)) /\ (forall x:X, Q (x))).

Can someone please help? I'm not sure whether to split, make an assumption etc.

My apologies for being a complete noob

Answer (score 4):

```
Goal forall (X : Type) (P Q : X->Prop), 
    (forall x : X, P x /\ Q x) -> (forall x : X, P x) /\ (forall x : X, Q x).
Proof.
  intros X P Q H; split; intro x; apply (H x).
Qed.
```

Comment: That's a nice example of using the (clever) `apply` tactic! Here is a tad shorter proof: `intros ? ? ? H; split; apply H.`

Answer (score 3):

Just some hints:
I recommand you use intros to name your hypothesis, split to separate the goals, 
and exact to provide the proof terms (which may involve proj1 or proj2).